# IE10: pointer-events: none still trigger the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, pointer-events

I have troubles with my app in IE <=10 .

And I'm using this [polyfill](https://github.com/kmewhort/pointer_events_polyfill)  to support `pointer-events: none` in IE

but still I'm able to click my element, in other browsers I'm not.

what I'm doing wrong?

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

    <div class="pointed" data-pointer-events-none>ClickME!</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
 $(window).load(function(){
  $('.pointed').click(function(){
    alert('clicked');
  });
  PointerEventsPolyfill.initialize({});
});
```

and [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DHmO8JOE7o6vkngVAXpD?p=preview):

why I still have not disabled the pointer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a polifyll you can use a simple jQuery to support IE,

see snippet below:

```js
$(document).on('mousedown', '.pointed', function(e) {
  $(this).hide();
  var PointerElement = document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  $(this).show();
  $(PointerElement).mousedown(); //Manually fire the event for desired underlying element
  return false;
});
```

```css
.pointed {
  pointer-events: none
  /*for every non-IE browser*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pointed">ClickME!</div>
```

Comment: @brabertaser1992 What a petty comment. His code is working and its correct - try to add the alert yourself.

Comment: @brabertaser1992 Hey don't start calling people dickhead, I didn't downvote you. Be friendly. Also0, if you used an alert in an SO snippet, they are blocked because of sandbox mode.